# Decay of a scalar Particle-Symmetry factors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism

Consider the Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L} = \dfrac{1}{2} (\partial_{\mu}\phi_{1})^2 + \dfrac{1}{2}(\partial_{\mu}\chi)^2 - \dfrac{M_1^2}{2}\phi_{1}^2 -\dfrac{M^2_\chi}{2} \chi^2 - \dfrac{\mu_\chi}{2} \phi_1\chi^2 $$

where $\phi_1$ and $\chi$ are real scalar fields.

The $\phi_1$ particle decays into the 2 identical $\chi$ particles.

Firstly,

When drawing the feynman diagram for the decay, should the amplitude of the vertex be -2$i\mu_{\chi}$ or just -$i\mu_{\chi}$ because the $\chi$ particles are identical? Or will this be taken care by the $\dfrac{1}{2}$ out front the interaction term? and I get only -$i\mu_{\chi}$

I know that the amplitude should have been -2$i\mu_{\chi}$ if there was no half in front of the coupling constant $\mu_{\chi}$, the 2 is because of the identical particles, but does that mean now that I have the half out front, the amplitude should be -$i\mu_{\chi}$ only?

Secondly,

When calculating the decay width, when I integrate d$\Pi_{LIPS}$, the integral over the solid angle d$\Omega$, should it be $4\pi$ or just $2\pi$ because of the identical particles? or will this again be taken care with the half out front the interaction term? and the solid angle should be $4\pi$ instead of $2\pi$

Answer (score 1):

To get the right vertex factor for the Feynman diagram, we use the rule: for every field $\phi$ that appears $n_\phi$ times in a given term, we should divide the term by $n_\phi!$ to leave the remaining factor as the actual vertex factor. Since $\phi_1$ appears once and $\chi$ twice in the final term, the normalisation of a $1/2$ is correct, and the vertex factor is just $-i\mu_\chi$.

You say you already know what should happen "if there was no half out front". It should be straightforward to convert between normalisations. Just think of $\mu_\chi/2$ as $\mu'$. Now there is no half out front, and so the Feynman rule is $-2i\mu'$, which is simply $-i\mu_\chi$.

The second 'symmetry factor', from the phase space integral, should be thought of separately, even if both factors have their roots in particle indistinguishability. The factor in the Feynman diagram comes from the combinatorics of how the fields in the S-matrix can act on the initial and final states, annihilating or creating particles. The factor in the phase space integral comes from considering which initial and final states we consider distinct, and which we consider identical.

In particular, a state with the first $\phi_1$ particle having momentum $\mathbf{p}$ and the second having momentum $\mathbf{q}$ is the same as the state with the first $\phi_1$ particle having momentum $\mathbf{q}$ and the second having momentum $\mathbf{p}$, by Bose statistics. In our case, in the rest frame of the $\chi$ particle, the two momenta must be equal and opposite, and so the phase space integral reduces merely to an integral over the direction $\mathbf{n}$ of the first one. But the state with the first particle leaving in direction $\mathbf{n}$ is identical to the state with the first particle leaving in direction $-\mathbf{n}$, so if we insist on integrating over *all* directions (read: solid angles), we need an accompanying factor of $1/2$.

Comment: So, does it mean even if I have the 1/2 out front, the vertex still gives $-i\mu_{\chi}$ even if the final particles are identical and even if we need to multiply by 2 to take into account the indistinguishability of the final particles? At the end of the day, the vertex still gives $-i\mu_{\chi}$ no matter what the normalisation factor out front? 
Again, in this case the final particles are identical, so does the integral over the solid angle should be only $2\pi$ because of the symmetry  factor involved?

Comment: The vertex factor certainly depends on the normalisation. If your Lagrangian contained the term $a\phi \chi^2$, the vertex factor would be $2ia$. If it contained the term $b \phi \chi^2/2$, it would be $ib$ (check that this is internally consistent). I describe in my post the 'canonical normalisation' needed to remove all numbers from the vertex factor. This depends on which particles are identical and which are not. For instance, a term $c \phi \chi \psi$ in the Lagrangian would have a vertex factor $ic$.

Comment: As far as the phase space integral goes, the accompanying factor should be $1/2$ multiplied by the integral over all directions. In this case, there is no direction-dependence of the integrand, so this just gives $1/2$ multiplied by $4 \pi$, which is indeed $2\pi$ as you suggest.

Comment: If there is the half in front, even though I have a symmetry because of the identical particles, I still get the −iμχ vertex and If suppose we have the final states as one particle and antiparticle pair (like the complex scalar field) I don't get the symmetry factor 2 because the particles are no longer identical, so in this case, if i have aϕχ2 i will get $ia$.

I got your point for the solid angle integral, so in this case for the identical final particles, it would be $2\pi$ and in the case of the particle-antiparticle pair, I will get the solid angle to be $4\pi$. Is this correct?

Comment: That sounds correct. To be clear, if $\chi$ is complex then with the term $a \phi \chi \chi^*$ in the Lagrangian the vertex factor would be $ia$.

Comment: Yes, for the final answer, taking into account the vertex to be $-i\mu_{chi}$ (including the identical particles symmetry factor of 2 and also the normalisation factor out front which is 1/2!), I got the decay width to be $$\Gamma = \dfrac{\mu^2_{\chi}}{32\pi M_1}\left(1-\dfrac{4\mu^2_{\chi}}{M^2_1}\right)^{1/2}$$

Is this answer legit? I have found online there is 8 instead of 32 in the denominator?

Comment: I agree with the $32$, if $M_1$ means $M_\chi$ and the $\mu_\chi$ in the square root is replaced by $M_\phi$.  There are many places you can lose a factor of two in these calculations besides symmetry factors; you'll need to post all of your working if you want help finding the error, in a separate question preferably.

Comment: Yes, $M_1$ is the mass of the $\phi$ particle and the $\mu_{\chi}$ is actually $M_1$ next to the 4 inside the bracket